# problem with assigning value to a unionized field of a struct

Tags: c, struct, unions

I am new here, hope that I can get some help.
After doing a tutorial about `structs` and `unions`, I practice what I learned, and want to combine two ideas. But I get an error that I've been trying to solve couple of hours, without any luck.

The code is:

```
void main(){

    typedef enum {INDIV, OUNCE, POUND } quantity;

    typedef union{

        short individual;
        float pound;
        float ounce;

    } amount;

    typedef struct{

        char *brand;
        amount theAmount;

    } orangeProduct;

    orangeProduct productOrdered;

    quantity quantityType = OUNCE;

    switch(quantityType)
    {
        case INDIV:
            productOrdered = {"Chiquita", .theAmount.individual = 13 };
            printf("You bought %d oranges\n\n", productOrdered.theAmount.individual)
            break;

    }
}
```

I have other cases as well, but this doesn't matter: if I solve the first one I will solve all of them.
The goal is to have structure which can hold brands of oranges, and for each brand hold the amount bought, the correct weight type.

The problem is with the line:

> productOrdered = {"Chiquita", productOrdered.theAmount.individual = 13 };

my `gcc compiiler` (using `codeBlocks`) is shouting at me:

> error: expected expression before '{' token|

and, no matter what I tried, it didn't help.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assigning To a Structure

The syntax of using braces (`{ .... }`) with a list of initial values for a structure can be used only when defining a structure, as in:

```
orangeProduct productOrdered = { "Chiquita", { 13 } };
```

You cannot use it in an assignment; this statement does not have correct grammar:

```
productOrdered = { "Chiquita", { 13 } };
```

There are two ways to **assign** values to a structure, rather than **initializing** it when it is defined. One is to assign to each member individually:

```
productOrdered.brand = "Chiquita";
productOrdered.theAmount.individual = 13;
```

Another is to copy it from another structure:

```
productOrdered = SomeOtherProduct;
```

We can use the above with another C feature called a *compound literal*. A compound literal can be used in an expression to provide an object without giving it a name. The general form of a compound literal is:

```
(type) { initial values... }
```

Although `(type)` looks like a cast, it is not. This syntax defines an object, and it can use the same syntax for initial values that is used in declarations. That means we can initialize a compound literal and assign it to a structure:

```
productOrdered = (orangeProduct) { "Chiquita", { 13 } };
```

### Other Notes About Assigning To a Structure

All of the following have the same effect:

```
productOrdered = (orangeProduct) { "Chiquita", { 13 } };
productOrdered = (orangeProduct) { "Chiquita", 13 };
productOrdered = (orangeProduct) { "Chiquita", { .individual = 13 } };
productOrdered = (orangeProduct) { "Chiquita", .theAmount.individual = 13 };
```

In the first of these, the inner braces indicate we are providing an initial value for a subobject of the main object—for the union `amount` inside the `orangeProduct`. As the second line shows, this is not required, because, if the braces are omitted, the compiler will take the ungrouped initial values and assign them to members of the subobjects anyway. However, it is good to include the braces explicitly, as it can avoid errors in more complicated aggregates and help convey intent to human readers.

The third and fourth forms show we can initial members using their names. This form is called designated initializers. They are most useful when you are skipping members in a structure or want to initialize a member of a union other than the first listed member.

However, another answer suggested this incorrect statement:

```
productOrdered = (orangeProduct){"Chiquita", productOrdered.theAmount.individual = 13 }
```

That is wrong because `productOrdered.theAmount.individual = 13` is not just an initial value; it is an assignment expression. It assigns 13 to `productOrdered.theAmount.individual`. The problem with this is that the whole statement also assigns values to `productOrdered`, including to `productOrdered.theAmount.individual`. This violates the rule in C 2018 6.5 2, which says:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined…

The two assignments to `productOrdered.theAmount.individual` are unsequenced because no rule of the C standard says when the assignments occur relative to each other. (When an assignment expression updates the value of an object, that is called a side effect, and it is not part of the main evaluation operation of an expression.)

### Other Notes

`main` should be declared with `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv)`, not with `void main()`. It can also be declared with specific forms allowed by your C implementation.

Include `#include <stdio.h>` in your code to declare `printf`.

Append a semicolon to this line:

```
printf("You bought %d oranges\n\n", productOrdered.theAmount.individual)
```

Comment: hi Eric,
great answer, i have learned alot, thank you! 
spent another couple of hours reading Supplemental Concepts as well.
if you can help me with a number of clarifications it will be supper:
1. if i would like to assign a value, not to the first member of the union, lets say to the second - "pound" - i would have to use third or fourth of the 4 methods that you wrote above? (the first and the second wouldn't help me, correct?)

2. i looked again and found the 6.5 2 comment, after reading it several times, it still isn't clear to me, Could you please interpret it in your own words?

Comment: @ArieCharfnadel: Yes, to initialize a member of a union other than the first listed member, you must use a designated initializer as shown in the third or fourth forms in the answer.

Comment: @ArieCharfnadel: The rules about side effects and sequencing are too involved to explain completely in a comment. Basically, expressions have main effects (`3*4` evaluates to 12, and `a = 3` evaluates to 3), and some expressions have side effects (`x++` increments `x` and `a = 3` sets `a` to 3). The C standard defines some ordering to some of these and leaves some ordering unspecified. One rule is that all side effects in an expression statement are complete before side effects in a later statement start.…

Comment: … So you can have `a++` in one statement and `a = 3` in another statement, and they will not get intertwined. But, if they are in the same statement, they might get intertwined—there might be no rule in the C standard that says one completes before the other starts. C clause 6.5, paragraph 2, says that, if a program does that with side effects that modify the same object, the behavior is not defined. Also, if one side effect on an object is possibly intertwined with one use of the value of an object, the behavior is not defined.